# Two submit buttons and 1 form not passing values

Tags: php, html, forms, onclick, submit

I have a php file which has one form and 2 submit buttons, onclick of 1 button it has to pass the value selected from a dropdown list. It is not passing the value to the php file which accepts POST data. But if I have only 1 button and the same form, this works fine.
Pl find my code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Invoice Printing</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showlink() 
{
window.open('invoiceprint2.php');
} 

function showlink3() 
{
window.open('invoiceprint3.php');
}   

</script>

</head>
<body>
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#026465">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><span class="style1"> Amogh Gases Private Ltd <br></span>
<center class="style5">INVOICE PRINTING</center>
<br><br>
<br>

</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--------------VALIDATIONS ------------------->

<br>
<br>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="" target="_blank">
<table width='40%' height='39'  border='0' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0'     align='center'>
<tr>
<td class='sty1'><div align='left'>Please select Invoice No. to PRINT: <br>
<br>
You can choose more than one invoice number from the options, by holding CTRL key on     your keyboard and select the numbers.</div></td>
<td>
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","tech1","te!@#");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("tech1", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Invno FROM INVHDR", $con);
echo "<select multiple='multiple' size='20' name='invnos[]'>";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{//Array or records stored in $nt
echo "<option value=$nt[Invno]>$nt[Invno]</option>";
/* Option values are added by looping through the array */
}
echo "</select>";// Closing of list box

mysql_close($con);
?>

</td>
</tr>
</table><br>


<center><input name="PRINT" type="button" value="PRINT Invoice to Laser Printer!"     onClick='showlink();' /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <input name="PRINT2" type="button" value="PRINT Invoice to Dotmatrix Printer !" onClick='showlink3();'/>

</form>

<br><br><br><br>
<a href='frameinvoice.php' target='_parent'><input name='Add' type='button'     value='Add'></a>  &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='invoice-edit.php' target='_parent'>  <input name='Edit' type='button' value='Edit !'></a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='invoice-cancel.php' target='_parent'><input name='Edit' type='button' value='Cancel !'></a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='index.htm' target='_parent'><input name='Close' type='button' value='CLOSE !'></a><br></center>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your "submit" buttons are PRINT and PRINT2?

Comment: @mate  Yes that's right, should I change name to submit for both the buttons ?

Comment: @Mate I tried changing the buttons name to submit, it does't work

Comment: No need to change them, please try the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Invoice Printing</title>

                <script type="text/javascript">

                    function postData(someValueToEvalute)
                    {



                        switch(someValueToEvalute){

                            case "1":{
                                    document.forms[0].action = 'invoiceprint2.php'
                                    break;
                                }
                            case "2":{
                                    document.forms[0].action = 'invoiceprint3.php'
                                    break;
                                }
                            default: { alert('fail');}

                        }
                        document.forms[0].submit();
                    }



                </script>

            </head>
            <body>
                <table width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#026465">
                    <tr>
                        <td><div align="center"><span class="style1"> Amogh Gases Private Ltd <br></span>
                                <center class="style5">INVOICE PRINTING</center>
                                <br><br>
                                <br>

                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>

                                <!--------------VALIDATIONS ------------------->

                                <br>
                                <br>

                                <form name="form1" method="post" action="" target="_blank">

                                <!-- PHP CODE REMOVED!!!!! --> 
                                    <center>
                                        <input name="PRINT" type="button" value="PRINT Invoice to Laser Printer!"     onClick='postData("1");' /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
                                        <input name="PRINT2" type="button" value="PRINT Invoice to Dotmatrix Printer !" onClick='postData("2");'/>

                                </form>

                                <br><br><br><br>
                                <a href='frameinvoice.php' target='_parent'><input name='Add' type='button'     value='Add'></a>  &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='invoice-edit.php' target='_parent'>  <input name='Edit' type='button' value='Edit !'></a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='invoice-cancel.php' target='_parent'><input name='Edit' type='button' value='Cancel !'></a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='index.htm' target='_parent'><input name='Close' type='button' value='CLOSE !'></a><br></center>
                                </center>

                                </body>
                                </html>
```

Comment: Great! Always assign a name more appropriate to name variables, for you and for anyone who needs to use the code in the future ;)

Comment: Sure will do that ! Thank you so much, it has saved a lot of time to move on !!